# Is qualified function type permitted as template parameter (C++98)

Tags: c++, c++98

I have three compilers (roughly C++98) that I am trying to compile some templates in.  The templates take a function type as an argument.

If I try to compile in a C++11 compiler then it just works if the function type is cv-qualified.  Two of the three C++98 compilers fail to compile if it is cv-qualified.

Is this correct behavior in a C++98 compiler?

Comment: Please provide the code and the compilers (with versions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the original C++98 standard did disallow applying the `const` qualifier to any function type, including template parameters.

This was later changed so that `const T` would always be valid but be equivalent to plain `T` for function types, but compilers implementing the original C++98 standard will detect `const T` as an error when `T` is a function type.

The defect report: [295. cv-qualifiers on function types](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#295).

Comment: That defect report is against C++98.  Was the behavior changed at all for C++03?

Comment: @Graznarak You pretty much answered your own question there. Yes.